# Форматирование частей текста

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли редактировать разные части текста в одном Label или RichTextBox? Чтобы текст был *таким* и **таким**, например.

Comment: Я, возможно, непонятно выразился. Нужно, чтобы в одном Label или RichTextBox бОльшая часть текста была со стандартным форматированием, но несколько слов курсивом. Можно ли этого добиться, и если да, то как?

Comment: [Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063263/make-portion-of-a-labels-text-to-be-styled-bold?lq=1), [RichTextBox](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/partially-bold-text-in-richtextbox1)

Comment: @timur эти элементы форматируют весь текст разом, не давая форматировать отдельные слова, хотя про RTB я не так сильно уверен, почему и спросил тут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите какую то часть текста выделить жирным или курсивом, то я думаю нужно использовать  RichTextBox, вызвать событие TextChanged и туда уже прописывать нужный для редактирования текст. Например, чтобы вывести текст "Система, в которой основной единицей расчета считается золото, называется **золотым стандартом**. *Дальше будет курсив.* А потом опять обычный текст." нужно прописать:

```
        private void RichTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
        richTextBox1.AppendText("Система, в которой основной единицей расчета считается золото, называется ");
       
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        richTextBox1.AppendText("золотым стандартом. ");

        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
        richTextBox1.AppendText("Дальше будет курсив. ");

        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
        richTextBox1.AppendText("А потом обычный текст.");
    }
```

И т.д. придется менять стиль текста в FontStyle и добавлять нужный текст с помощью AppendText. Тогда на форме это будет выглядеть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]